# Minecraft forge-1.19.3 World data

Tags: java, minecraft-forge

I know that with this you can save something in nbt player:

```
player.getPersistentData().putString("a", "b");
```

But with this, it could not be saved for all players. Is there a way to save the same things (a, b) for all players with the same code, or to save this for the world?
Sorry for the bad grammar, I use google translate.

Comment: Why don't simply iterate over all players?

Comment: @Elikill58 
`player.getLevel().players().forEach(player -> {player.getPersistentData().putString("a", "b");});`
Is it correct?

Comment: @Elikill58
I have another question about this.
How can I get all persistent data of a player?

Comment: idk if it's correct but I were thinking about something like that. For your second question, I don't really know, maybe there is method on the getPersistentData() object